How do I create a Solana RPC connection using TypeScript/JavaScript?
The Solana RPC offers several methods you can call to read and write from the network. How would I use @solana/web3.js in TypeScript/JavaScript to create a connection against which I can call these methods?

Installation
Install @solana/web3.js into your project.
npm install @solana/web3.js@2

Quick Start
Create a default RPC instance using the URL of a public RPC.
import { createSolanaRpc } from '@solana/web3.js';

const rpc = createSolanaRpc('https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com');

When you need more than the public RPC can offer in terms of rate limits and features, search for and hire a third-party RPC provider.
From a specific cluster
The devnet cluster, for instance, offers methods that the mainnet cluster does not – such as the ability to airdrop test tokens to any account.
import { createSolanaRpc, devnet } from '@solana/web3.js';

const rpcDevnet = createSolanaRpc(devnet('https://api.devnet.solana.com'));

RPC instances created like this gain a requestAirdrop() method.
Using a custom network transport
If you need to customize something about the transport – like add an HTTP header or supply a custom Undici dispatcher, you can do this.
import {
    createDefaultRpcTransport,
    createSolanaRpcFromTransport,
    mainnet,
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Agent } from 'undici';

const transport = createDefaultRpcTransport({
    dispatcher_NODE_ONLY: new Agent({
        keepAliveTimeout: 10,
        keepAliveMaxTimeout: 10,
    }),
    headers: { Authorization: '...' },
    url: mainnet('https://some.rpc'),
});
const rpc = createSolanaRpcFromTransport(transport);

